# API Key authorization issue in openai

Tags: asp.net, web

I have created API key through chatgpt APikey but I still have an authorize issue (this ApiKey is an example).

```
private async Task<string> CallOpenAiApi(string message)
{
     var apiUrl = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";
     var apiKey = "sk-bkE9vdwOAzMGVQlOXKDXT3BlbkFDroto7f";

     using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
     {
         httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiKey);
         httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

         var requestData = CreateOpenAiRequestData(message);

         var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

         try
         {
             var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(apiUrl, content);
            
             if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
             {
                 var responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                 var processedMessage = ParseOpenAiResponse(responseData);

                 return processedMessage;
             }
             else
             {
                 return "Error processing message with OpenAI";
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             return "Exception during OpenAI API request: " + ex.Message;
         }
     }
}
```

This response is returned:

```
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Fri, 26 Jan 2024 19:58:53 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  Vary: Origin
  X-Request-ID: 235928e
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15800; includeSubDomains
  CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
  Set-Cookie: __cf_bm=MXjmUHqakbB8erUAv8CcwPOFiJ6e1V6pjMZloCY.l1I-1706293-1-AfJzBPDrrlONiZ1nf4zGgQL/xFW4dP2Aaqyswd27dgMvF92nftPAQkzYk=; path=/; expires=Fri, 26-Jan-24 20:28:53 GMT; domain=.api.openai.com; HttpOnly; Secure
  Set-Cookie: _cfuvid=vjZDRDMNJ5K6g-1706299133636-0-604800000; path=/; domain=.api.openai.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
  Server: cloudflare
  CF-RAY: 84bdde43-MCT
  Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=840
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 169
}
}
```